# Tab Using Pure CSS Flex Concept

Tags: tabs, flexbox

How do I separate a flex item from its flex container and make it block width 100% using css without positioning?

My HTML structure:

```
<div class="container">
  <div style="display:flex;">
    <div>tab</div>
    <div class="block-container">content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGZAH.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The rule you need to add is `flex-wrap: wrap;`. Once we add this to the `.container`, making `.block-container` 100% wide forces it to a new line, away from the `.tab`.

```css
.container {
  display:flex; 
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.tab, .block-container {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}

.tab {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}

.block-container {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab">tab</div>
  <div class="block-container">content</div>
</div>
```